# Add click back to unbinded event

Tags: jquery, click, bind, unbind

When I run the following code, i only want the #overlay, #image + theNumber, and #close to be active so i am disabling $('.box').click but once #close is clicked i want to re-enable the click on $('.box') but I am unable to thus far.  I've checked out other answers and wasn't able to put it together.  Thanks for the help!!

```
var handler = function() {

var theIDval = $(this).attr('id');
var theNumber = theIDval.replace('box','');

    $('.box').unbind('click');

    $('#overlay').show();
    $('#image' + theNumber).fadeIn();
    $('#close').fadeIn();

    $('#close').click( function () {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut();
        $('#image' + theNumber).fadeOut();
        $('#close').fadeOut();

        });
    };

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.box').click(handler);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like all you're missing is re-binding the `.box` click event in your `#close` click handler function

```
$('#close').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
    $('#image' + theNumber).fadeOut();
    $('#close').fadeOut();
    $('.box').click(handler);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/gUP68/

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would do it like this:

```
var handler = function() {
    var $box = $('.box');
    if($box.hasClass('disabled')){
       // do nothing, just disallow further spawns
   } else{
        $box.addClass('disabled');
        var theIDval = $(this).attr('id');
        var theNumber = theIDval.replace('box','');

        // no need to unbind, remove this
        // $('.box').unbind('click');

        $('#overlay').show();
        $('#image' + theNumber).fadeIn();
        $('#close').fadeIn();

        $('#close').click( function () {
            $('#overlay').fadeOut();
            $('#image' + theNumber).fadeOut();
            $('#close').fadeOut();
            $box.removeClass('disabled'); // re-enable click
        });
   }
};

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.box').click(handler);
});
```

Comment: this also worked but the other answer is more concise. thank you for your help!